# Angular - Confirmation to child on parent event complete

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-components

**Context:**
Working on generic data table which has an inline edit feature.

**Components:**

parent most component - `data.table.component.(ts|html|css)`
child component - `data.row.component.(ts|html|css)`
child component - `data.cell.component.(ts|html|css)`

**Process:**
the inline edit feature is enabled from data.cell.component, on edit complete(either by enter key or blur) event will be sent to data.row.component and then to table.component.ts, this event will be sent to whoever using table component($event payload has information about which row is edited, which column and what is the new value)

**Problem:**
once consumer updates new values in the database (Async), How can I tell table component update has been successful or fail ?

Comment: I suggest you to close the issue https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/27617, since it is not a bug/feature but a support question.

Comment: Hey Esteban, thanks for your response, Since i was not getting any response here. I opened in github issues.. sorry for that.. I will close this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to create a service that provides an observable (subject). The data-table component will subscribe to that observable and will be notified once the async-component updates that observable.
Example:

```
@Injectable()
export class SaveNotificationService {
  public saveDone: Subject<void> = new Subject<void>();
}
```

In your data-table component you then have

```
constructor(private saveNotificationService: SaveNotificationService) {
  this.saveNotificationService.saveDone
    .pipe(takeUntil(this._destroyed))
    .subscribe(() => {
      // do the refresh here
    })
}
```

and in your async component saving the data you would have

```
saveData() {
  this.http.post(...).subscribe(() => {
    this.saveNotificationService.saveDone.next();
  })
}
```